# Make search case insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, case-insensitive

Below in the JSFiddle link I have a project for a country selection filter.

In the search bar you can fill out a country you want in your filter. However it only works if you use lowercases. I tried to edit my css to transform the text into lowercase but whenever you use capitals it still doesnt work. So I think ill have to adjust the script.

However I don't know how to make this script case insensitive.
Can you help me out?
https://jsfiddle.net/Sentah/d8so22xj/

```
$("#countryName").focus(function()
    {
        if ($(this).val() === $(this)[0].title)
        {
            $(this).removeClass("default_text_active");
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });

    $("#countryName").blur(function()
    {
        if ($(this).val() === "")
        {
            $(this).addClass("default_text_active");
            $(this).val($(this)[0].title);
        }
    });

    $("#countryName").blur(); 


    $('#countryName').on('keyup', function() {
        var query = this.value;
        $('[id^="chk_country"]').each(function(i, elem) {
              if (elem.value.indexOf(query) != -1) {
                  elem.style.display = 'inline';
                  $("#lbl_for_" + elem.getAttribute("id")).removeClass("hidden") ;
              }else{
                  elem.style.display = 'none';
                  $("#lbl_for_" + elem.getAttribute("id")).addClass("hidden");
              }
        });
    });
```

Comment: use this code in your code  elem.value.indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) so what ever enter in text box it gives you sting in lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code use [query.toLowerCase()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) to convert text in to LowerCase.

```
$('#countryName').on('keyup', function() {
    var query = this.value;
    $('[id^="chk_country"]').each(function(i, elem) {
          if (elem.value.indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
              elem.style.display = 'inline';
              $("#lbl_for_" + elem.getAttribute("id")).removeClass("hidden") ;
          }else{
              elem.style.display = 'none';
              $("#lbl_for_" + elem.getAttribute("id")).addClass("hidden");
          }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `elem.value` in the `keyup` handler block is all lowercase. As such, to make the match case-insensitive you need to convert the value the user typed lowercase too by using `query.toLowerCase()`. Try this:

```
$('#countryName').on('keyup', function () {
    var query = this.value;
    $('[id^="chk_country"]').each(function (i, elem) {
        if (elem.value.indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) != -1) { // note toLowerCase here
            elem.style.display = 'inline';
            $("#lbl_for_" + elem.getAttribute("id")).removeClass("hidden");
        } else {
            elem.style.display = 'none';
            $("#lbl_for_" + elem.getAttribute("id")).addClass("hidden");
        }
    });
});
```